# How to return a node in a list in C

Tags: c, list

I have a requirement to implement two functions

`directed_by(node_t * list, char * director)`

`rated(node_t * list, const rating_t rating)`

Each will require I pass in a list and iterate through it.  I'm new to C and actually I'm not that familiar with list structures either.  Can someone please help me understand how do I return a list so that I can pass into my two functions so that I can iterate through each list?

Here is my code so far.  I think I need to return something in my `add_movie()` function, such as node_t, but I'm not sure how to do that?

LIST.H

```
#ifndef BASICLIST_H_
#define BASICLIST_H_

typedef struct node {
  void * data;         /* pointer to data */
  struct node * next;  /* pointer to next next node */
} node_t;

int list_add(node_t ** list, void * data);

#endif
```

MOVIE.H

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef MOVIE_H
#define MOVIE_H
#define SIZE_LIMIT 25
#define RATING_SIZE 6

typedef struct {
    char title[SIZE_LIMIT];
    char director[SIZE_LIMIT];
    char rating[RATING_SIZE];
    //rating_t rating;
    int year;
}movie_t;


void get_movie(movie_t * movie);
void print_movie(const movie_t *m);
void print_movies(const movie_t *m);
void add_movie(movie_t movie);

#endif /* MOVIE_H */
```

LIST.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"basiclist.h"

int list_add(node_t ** list, void * data) {
  int ret = 0;
  node_t * newnode = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  if (newnode == NULL) {
    ret = -1;
  }
  else {
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = *list;
  }
  *list = newnode;
  return ret;
}
```

MOVIE.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "movie.h"
#include "basiclist.h"

void print_movies(const movie_t *m) {
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\n", m->title, m->director, m->rating, m->year);
}

void add_movie(movie_t movie) {
    node_t * list = NULL;
    movie_t first_movie = movie;
    movie_t * new_movie;
    new_movie = malloc(sizeof (*new_movie));
    *new_movie = first_movie;
    list_add(&list, new_movie);
    node_t * curr;
    curr = list;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        print_movies(curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

MAIN.C

```
#include "movie.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "basiclist.h"

int main(void) {
    movie_t movie1 = {"Movie1", "Director1", "PG-13", 1900};
    movie_t movie2 = {"Movie2", "Director2", "R", 1900};
    movie_t movie3 = {"Movie3", "Director3", "G", 1900};
    movie_t movie4 = {"Movie4", "Director4", "R", 1900};

    add_movie(movie1);
    add_movie(movie2);
    add_movie(movie3);
    add_movie(movie4); 

    /*undefined methods
    directed_by(node_t * list, char * director)
    rated(node_t * list, const rating_t rating)
    */    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your get and add functions shouldn't return void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with this code is that you are not returning or passing your list to the add_movie function.

In each call you are creating a new list and losing it's reference, so you can't use it.

The "easy" fix to your code would be to change:

```
void add_movie(movie_t movie)
```

to

```
void add_movie(node_t** list, movie_t movie);
```

and remove the first line of the function, then change your main to:

```
node_t* list = NULL;
add_movie(&list, movie1);
add_movie(&list, movie2);
add_movie(&list, movie3);
add_movie(&list, movie4);
```

With this change you will have the list with movie4, movie3, movie2 and movie1.

**PS**: you also want to change your list add method to return -1 instead of setting ret to -1. In its current form you would lose your list in case of an error because you are setting the given reference to NULL (also, that would create a memory leak).

**PS 2**: It is not really recommended to pass structs as arguments in C, you should use pointers instead. The reason is that when you pass a struct as argument C will copy its whole content to a temporary struct variable, so if you have, say, a 256 bytes struct you will be copying 256 bytes of information for every function call, instead of 4 (32 bits systems) or 8 (64 bits systems) if you had used a pointer.

Comment: @Fernanon Coelho Thanks for the help that does make sense (and PS comments).  Although I do get segfault after making your modifications.  Did I miss something? Here is my current code, https://github.com/anonmouseperson1234/c_list

Comment: I didn't run it, but in a fast look, it should be "list" not "&list" here:
https://github.com/anonmouseperson1234/c_list/blob/master/movie.c#L15

Comment: It worked by removing the & from the list when calling add_movie(&list, movie1);